# Need help filtering the chat, the code doesn't work

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I write words from bad_list, but the bot doesn't delete them ,what did I do wrong ?

```
bad_list = ['toy', 'hack']
@client.event
async def on_message( message ):
    await client.process_commands( message )

    msg = message.content.lower()

    if msg in bad_list:
        await message.delete()
        await message.author.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{message.author},такие слова не допустимы!',color = 0xff0000))
```

there are no errors in the command line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swqPK.png)

Comment: If I'm not mistaken process_commands is a blocking call... try placing the filter first

Comment: I deleted the code `await client.process_commands( message )` doesn't work @KingsleyZhong

Comment: You should place ``await client.process_commands(message)`` at the end of your ``on_message`` event. Also I'm unable to reproduce your issue, your code seems to work fine on my end. Are you sure the bot has the appropriate permissions?

Comment: Is it possible that the code doesn't work if it's large? [image](https://sun9-42.userapi.com/BPL8pFpjBTiulWBk47pddp1IDJrPtUqfe4MHng/PIefaVNOWs4.jpg)
is it possible that the code doesn't work if there is another one?[image](https://sun9-60.userapi.com/nzE35vT54bnMH5s97n8XiYm_uQxiKD20Wo5B3A/InTEwuRv59E.jpg) @Jawad

Answer (score 1):

You compare the complete message, which is stored in `msg` to the words in your `bad_list`. This will only ever be true if a comment consists solely of one of the words in your list.

Instead, you should check, whether any of the bad words appear *within* the message. For this purpose, you would have to change the if-statement:

```
    is_bad = False
    for w in bad_list:
        if w in msg: is_bad=True
    if is_bad:
        await message.delete()
        await message.author.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f'{message.author},такие слова не допустимы!',color = 0xff0000))
```

Using this modification, the program searches for any bad word within the message and switches to deleting as soon as a bad word is detected.

One problem remains, though. If the message contains a word that only contains these strings without being a bad word, it will also be deleted (e.g.: shackles, latoya). You'd better search for the words preceded by a blank. So, it will only remove hacking, hacked, hacker...

`if ' '+w in msg: is_bad=True`